# Reference a field from Subform as a Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form [form1] with a subform [subForm1]. 
[subForm1] contains a data table with fields "day", "month", and "year".

In [subForm1], I have 3 textbox "dayText", "monthText", and "yearText" that each have a control source from the corresponding fields from the data table.

I am trying to write a macro that uses the "year" field value from the row that is currently selected in the subform. So if I select the first row and run the macro, I want the macro to use the value "2019".

```
day month year
1   1     2019
2   3     2017
```

This is what I have tried so far and this is the error I get. I appreciate any inputs. Thanks

```
Declare yearStr as String
yearStr = Forms![form1].[subForm1].Form!yearText

Error - Cant't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.
```

Edit: I found that Me.CurrentRecord will give me the index of the row, but I'm not sure how to use that to get the value of a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

Me![year] ended up working. Was a lot easier than I expected.